# Retrieve the value of a global variable in aspx.vb page from another aspx.vb page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have declared a variable in default.aspx.vb as follows:

Public name as string

and I have given the value to it as

name = txtname.text

Now I want to have this value in txtname.text on another page called exam.aspx.vb

How is this possible ?

Comment: It doesn't work that way.  Pages are not kept in memory.  You need to store it somewhere (eg, session)

Comment: can you give me some hint about session and global variables

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Session variable to access the value in this case.

This is how to assign value to session variable

```
Session("name") = txtname.Text;
```

and access it like this on any other page

```
If Session("name") IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim value As String = Session("name").ToString()
End If
```